# Vectorization with lists (as tibble columns) in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, purrr, tibble

I am dealing with time series data for different individuals in a wide format. The number of time points differ between individuals. Now, the thing is that I need the last element for each individual.

I was thinking of using a list as a column in my tibble to store the time series sequences.
(Putting each time point into a different column is probably not a good idea, since there can be hundreds of possible time points, but an individual could have data only for a handful of them, however, the data per individual is always measured for consecutive time points.)

Let's call it column1, i.e.:

```
library(tibble)
# Create an example dataframe
df <- tibble(
  column1 = list(1:3, 1:4, 4:8)
)
```

Now, I would like to use a vectorization for the sake of efficiency and speed, but is it even possible with the given data structure. There is a function called map() in purrr package, with which the operation would go like:

```
library(purrr)

# Use the map function to select the last element of each vector
last_elements <- map(df$column1, ~ .x[length(.x)])
```

But this is not vectorization, but rather looping through the elements of the list (stored as column1), right?

Would there be a better (i.e. faster / more efficient) choice for a data structure than a list as a column? Or is this in general the best way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that `vectorization` in `R` means that you do not need a loop, b/c somebody **else** did the loop already for you. Important part is that eventually there will be some sort of loop.

The reason why "often" relying on out-of-the-shelf vectorization is faster than writing your loop yourself is that the loop in the former case is done on `C` level, which *can* be faster, but sometimes the difference is not even noticeable:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
x <- seq_len(10000000L)
 
microbenchmark(
  vec = sum(x),
  lp = {sm <- 0; for(i in seq_along(x)) sm <- sm + x[i]; sm}
)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   vec       100       200      2745       350      4450     19300   100  a 
#    lp 327515400 340921350 367242236 351582100 383396050 603997400   100   b
```

Looks like a lot, but be aware of the unit, so basically the loop finishes in `0.32sec` while the `R` loop takes `0.0000001sec`. In relative terms this is a huge improvement, but in absolute terms you barely will see a difference.

Bottom line is that you should not be afraid of `R`-level loops, b/c they are far better than their reputation. If there's a natural replacement for a loop, go for it by all means, but do not hesitate to use them when the price for avoiding them is an over-bloated data structure.

Now to your problem at hand.

You *could* transform your data into long format and take the last row by individual. You can go even further and use `data.table` with an appropriate key:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

create_data <- function(nr_indiv, max_per_indiv) {
  l <- replicate(nr_indiv, sample(10000L, sample(max_per_indiv, 1L)))
  tibble(id = seq_len(nr_indiv), load = l)
}

set.seed(20022024)
list_data <- create_data(10000, 1000)
lng_data <- unnest(list_data, cols = load)
dt_data <- copy(lng_data)
setDT(dt_data)
setkey(dt_data, "id")

my_check <- function(x) {
  isTRUE(all.equal(x$lst, x$lng %>% pull(load), check.attributes = FALSE)) &&
  isTRUE(all.equal(x$lst, x$dt[, load], check.attributes = FALSE)) &&
  isTRUE(all.equal(x$lst, c(x$ta), check.attributes = FALSE)) &&
  isTRUE(all.equal(x$lst, x$base, check.attributes = FALSE)) &&
  isTRUE(all.equal(x$lst, x$flt %>% pull(load), check.attributes = FALSE))
}

microbenchmark(
  lst = map_int(list_data$load, tail, n = 1L),
  lng = slice_tail(lng_data, n = 1L, by = id), 
  dt = dt_data[, .(load = tail(load, 1L)), "id"], 
  ta = tapply(lng_data$load, lng_data$id, tail, n = 1L),
  base = vapply(list_data$load, tail, integer(1L), n = 1L),
  flt = lng_data %>% filter(ord == 1L),
  check = my_check
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval   cld
#   lst  70.5403  77.40405   93.87981   87.87985  101.53635  280.5060   100 a    
#   lng 916.2937 971.14420 1053.53934 1004.19125 1133.12665 1434.2933   100  b   
#    dt  18.4768  19.47870   28.12581   20.64565   37.49055   64.8045   100   c  
#    ta 315.0710 357.06000  407.04557  368.03110  453.28390  687.4518   100    d 
#  base  65.5528  75.40010   85.31279   85.87180   94.14265  116.5428   100 a    
#   flt  44.4467  47.46310   55.71809   50.85525   57.62820  244.5270   100     e
```

The `tidyverse` long format solution is worse than the `purrr` loop, the `data.table` long format solution, is better (not accounting for the overhead of creating the data structure), the filter method lies in between and base loops are at par with `purrr` so even the slight overhead of `purrr` is negligible.

There will be even more solutions, but from this first quick test, it seems to me that the `list` solution is not that bad overall, and, in my opinion equally (if not even more) importantly, quite easy to read and understand.

TL;DR: Don't be afraid of loops, if there is no straight forward natural vectorization method use them by all means.